# How to extract all YouTube comments using YouTube API? (Python)

Tags: python, list, youtube, youtube-api

Let's say I have a `video_id` having `8487` comments.
This code returns only `4309` comments.

```
def get_comments(youtube, video_id, comments=[], token=''):

  video_response=youtube.commentThreads().list(part='snippet',
                                               videoId=video_id,
                                               pageToken=token).execute()
  for item in video_response['items']:
        comment = item['snippet']['topLevelComment']
        text = comment['snippet']['textDisplay']
        comments.append(text)
  if "nextPageToken" in video_response: 
    return get_comments(youtube, video_id, comments, video_response['nextPageToken'])
  else:
    return comments

youtube = build('youtube', 'v3',developerKey=api_key)
comment_threads = get_comments(youtube,video_id)
print(len(comment_threads))

> 4309
```

How can I extract all the `8487` comments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the answer of `commentThreads`, you have to add the `replies` parameter in order to retrieve the replies the comments might have.

So, your request should look like this:

```
video_response=youtube.commentThreads().list(part='id,snippet,replies',
                                               videoId=video_id,
                                               pageToken=token).execute()
```

Then, modify your code accordingly for read the `replies` of the comments.

In this [example I made](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%2Csnippet%2Creplies%22%5D%2C%22maxResults%22%3A100%2C%22videoId%22%3A%22ouf0ozwnU84%22%7D) using the try-it feature available in the documentation, you can check that the reponse contains both, the top comment and its replies.

---

Edit (*08/04/2022*):

Create a new variable that contains the **`totalReplyCount`** that the `topLevelComment` *might* have.

Something like:

```
def get_comments(youtube, video_id, comments=[], token=''):

  # Stores the total reply count a top level commnet has.
  totalReplyCount = 0
  
  # Replies of the top-level comment might have.
  replies=[]

  video_response=youtube.commentThreads().list(part='snippet',
                                               videoId=video_id,
                                               pageToken=token).execute()
      for item in video_response['items']:
            comment = item['snippet']['topLevelComment']
            text = comment['snippet']['textDisplay']
            comments.append(text)

            # Get the total reply count: 
            totalReplyCount = item['snippet']['totalReplyCount']
            
            # Check if the total reply count is greater than zero, 
            # if so,call the new function "getAllTopLevelCommentReplies(topCommentId, replies, token)" 
            # and extend the "comments" returned list.
            if (totalReplyCount > 0): 
               comments.extend(getAllTopLevelCommentReplies(comment['id'], replies, None)) 
               
            # Clear variable - just in case - not sure if need due "get_comments" function initializes the variable.
            replies = []

      if "nextPageToken" in video_response: 
        return get_comments(youtube, video_id, comments, video_response['nextPageToken'])
      else:
        return comments
```

Then, if the value of `totalReplyCount` is greater than zero, make another call using the [comment.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list) for bring the replies the top level comment has.
For this new call, you have to pass the id of the top level comment.

Example (*untested*):

```
# Returns all replies the top-level comment has: 
# topCommentId = it's the id of the top-level comment you want to retrieve its replies.
# replies = array of replies returned by this function. 
# token = the comments.list might return moren than 100 comments, if so, use the nextPageToken for retrieve the next batch of results.
def getAllTopLevelCommentReplies(topCommentId, replies, token): 
    replies_response=youtube.comments().list(part='snippet',
                                               maxResults=100,
                                               parentId=topCommentId
                                               pageToken=token).execute()

  for item in replies_response['items']:
        # Append the reply's text to the 
        replies.append(item['snippet']['textDisplay'])

  if "nextPageToken" in replies_response: 
    return getAllTopLevelCommentReplies(topCommentId, replies, replies_response['nextPageToken'])
  else:
    return replies
```

---

Edit (*11/04/2022*):

I've added the [Google Colab example](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1uA1FadxpjOW2sj2FaQc6rFiy-n0G_6ZK?usp=sharing) I modified based on your code and it works with my video example (*ouf0ozwnU84*) = it brings its 130 comments, but, with your video example (*BaGgScV4NN8*) I got 3300 of 3359.

This might be some comments could be under approval/moderation or something else I'm missing or *probably* there are comments too old and additional filters are needed, or the API is buggy - [see here some other questions related to troubles facing with the pagination using the API](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=youtube%20data%20api%20comment%20pagination) - I suggest you to check this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=?B9uCX2s7y7A) which shows code and you can change it.

Comment: Still didn't work. There were only few replies around 50.

Comment: @Subham add `maxResults=100` and (*if possible*), try this code with a video that has less comments.

Comment: @Subham if you try with this video "*`ouf0ozwnU84`*" - how many comments do you get¡

Comment: That video has a total of 130 comments. The code above returned 90, with ```maxResults=100``` and ```part='snippet,replies'```

Comment: If you know any other way to extract all the comments rather than using YouTube's API do let me know.

Comment: @Subham hmm... then, in the "snippet" response, check if the "totalReplyCount" is grater than zero, if so, make a second call to "comments" endpoint - by passing the "parentId" of the comment - see [example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%2Csnippet%22%5D%2C%22maxResults%22%3A100%2C%22parentId%22%3A%22UgzNNzns2n3bYWKiGTR4AaABAg%22%7D) - notice that if the replies are more than 100, you need to use the "nextPageToken" value for get the next batch. Hope it helps.

Comment: I didn’t get you. Could you please edit your comment? It would be a great help for me. I have been stuck on this for days..

Comment: @Subham I edited my answer. Hope it helps. if not, please, consider user Google Colab for create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and I might give it a second try - don't include there you API key, though.

Comment: Hey, man thanks a lot for your time. Still few comments are yet to be retrieved. Out of `2312`, `2224` comments are retrieved. Here's my colab [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12RWPS5HBLKzHlF1r6niGmkYmFq7BSWFd?usp=sharing). If you can do give it a try in there.

Comment: @Subham I try and with my video example (*ouf0ozwnU84*) I got the 130 comments that the video has so far, but, with your video example (*BaGgScV4NN8*) I got 3300 of 3359. This might be some comments could be under approval/moderation or  something else I'm missing or the API is buggy [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=youtube+data+api+comment+pagination) - I suggest you to check this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=?B9uCX2s7y7A). The changes I made were for variable naming mostly.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your time. If you can upvote the question.

Comment: @Subham sure. I also found this video on YouTube - v=B9uCX2s7y7A - and it seems plausible (*if you want to keep trying*). Best of luck.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes how to separate the comment and replies with other information such as likes , I tired but it don't work