# Scrape all youtube comment using Youtube API and python

Tags: python, web-scraping, youtube, youtube-api

I'd like to scrape all the comments on some youtube videos using the youtube API, but I'm having trouble exceeding the 100 maxresult. This is my code:

```
video_response = youtube.commentThreads().list(part='snippet, replies',videoId=video_id, maxResults=100, pageToken=pageToken if pageToken != "" else "").execute()

for item in video_response['items']:

   comment = item['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textDisplay']
   date = item['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['publishedAt']
   count = item['snippet']['totalReplyCount']

   if  count > 0:
       parent_id = item['snippet']['topLevelComment']['id']
       response = youtube.comments().list(part="snippet", parentId=parent_id).execute()

   for x in response['items']:
       print(x['snippet']['textDisplay'])
    
   if "nextPageToken" in video_response:
       pageToken = video_response.get('nextPageToken')
```

The comments sometimes are over 4k and no metter what I always get only 100 results. What am I doing wrong?
Thakn you all

Comment: I think you need to add more code - see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71785217/12511801) for more guidance.

Comment: `youtube.commentThreads().list` seems to be executed once, this seems to be the problem.