# Is it possible to write a program that checks if a pinned comment is present under a Youtube video every certain period of time? (using python?)

Tags: python, youtube

**I'm not asking for someone to write out specific codes for me, but rather just point me towards the general direction.**

Sometimes after writing and pinning a comment under a Youtube video, it disappears!

It may happen hours later, it may happen a few minutes later, all randomly. Then re-appears hours later, not sure why.

Since I am currently learning programming (python), I might as well try to tackle the problem myself. I want to make a program that regularly checks if the pinned comment is still present, and if not, send me an alert in whatever way so I can go write and pin a new comment for the time being. (and maybe learn a few things during the process)

So far I learned some basic stuff like how to get source code from a webpage, output it to somewhere like a txt file, and also searching with Regex. However when I check out the source code of a Youtube video, the comments text aren't there. Where do I begin learning about the necessary things needed to make this program work?

Comment: Looks like there's a `youtube` library that can fetch comments, I'd start by looking at that - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71768274/how-to-extract-all-youtube-comments-using-youtube-api-python

Comment: If you are really looking for a web-scraping solution, have a look to the JSON encoded JavaScript string variable that `ytInitialData` is.