# How to get more than 500 comments of Youtube video using Youtube Data API

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api

I've tried get Youtube comments using Youtube Data API dan Python, but i still can't catch all the comments, as example a video have 36,000 comments but only catch 20,000 comments.

I tried it two ways, in this first way the comment retrieval process took a long time, would be faster if the ```if "nextPageToken" in response....`` is not use.

```
def get_comments(youtube, video_id, token):
  komentar = []
  request = youtube.commentThreads().list(part='snippet, replies', videoId= video_id, maxResults = 10)
  response = request.execute()

  for idx, cmt in enumerate(response['items']):
    topLvl = dict(
        videoId = cmt['snippet']['videoId'],
        commentId = cmt['snippet']['topLevelComment']['id'],
        username = cmt['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['authorDisplayName'],
        comment = cmt['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textDisplay'],
        likeCount = cmt['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['likeCount'],
        publishedAt = cmt['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['publishedAt'])
    komentar.append(topLvl)

    if 'replies' in response['items'][idx]:
      for v in range(len(response['items'][idx]['replies']['comments'])):
        replies1 = dict(
            video_id = cmt['replies']['comments'][v]['snippet']['videoId'],
                        commentId = cmt['replies']['comments'][v]['id'],
                        parentId = cmt['replies']['comments'][v]['snippet']['parentId'],
                        username = cmt['replies']['comments'][v]['snippet']['authorDisplayName'],
                        comment = cmt['replies']['comments'][v]['snippet']['textDisplay'],
                        likeCount = cmt['replies']['comments'][v]['snippet']['likeCount'],
                        publishedAt = cmt['replies']['comments'][v]['snippet']['publishedAt'])
        # print("rep 1: ", replies1)
        komentar.append(replies1)
    
    totalReplyCount = cmt['snippet']['totalReplyCount']
    replies_response=youtube.comments().list(part='snippet',maxResults=100,parentId=cmt['id']).execute()
    for indx, reply in enumerate(replies_response['items']):
      # print("pp ", reply['snippet']['authorDisplayName'])
      replies2 = dict(
          # video_id = reply['videoId'],
                    commentId = reply['id'],
                    parentId = reply['snippet']['parentId'],
                    username = reply['snippet']['authorDisplayName'],
                    comment = reply['snippet']['textDisplay'],
                    likeCount = reply['snippet']['likeCount'],
                    publishedAt = reply['snippet']['publishedAt'])
      # print("rep 2: ", replies2)
      komentar.append(replies2)

      while "nextPageToken" in replies_response:
        token_reply = replies_response['nextPageToken']
        replies_response=youtube.comments().list(part='snippet',maxResults=100,parentId=cmt['id'],pageToken=token_reply).execute()
        for indx, reply in enumerate(replies_response['items']):
          replies3 = dict(
              commentId = reply['id'],
                        parentId = reply['snippet']['parentId'],
                        username = reply['snippet']['authorDisplayName'],
                        comment = reply['snippet']['textDisplay'],
                        likeCount = reply['snippet']['likeCount'],
                        publishedAt = reply['snippet']['publishedAt'])
          # print("rep 3: ", replies3)
          komentar.append(replies3)
        
  if "nextPageToken" in response: 
    return get_comments(youtube, video_id, response['nextPageToken']) 
  else: 
    komentar = [x for x in komentar if len(x) > 0]
    return []
  return komentar
```

This second method has many lines of code, even repetitive. But in this way can get more comment data

```
def video_comments(youtube, video_ids):
        all_comments = []

        request = youtube.commentThreads().list(part='snippet, replies', videoId= video_id, maxResults = 100)
        response = request.execute()
    
        for i in range(0, len(response['items'])):
            
            data = dict(
                video_id = response['items'][i]['snippet']['videoId'],
                commentId = response['items'][i]['snippet']['topLevelComment']['id'],
                username = response['items'][i]['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['authorDisplayName'],
                comment = response['items'][i]['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textDisplay'],
                like = response['items'][i]['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['likeCount'],
                totalReply = response['items'][i]['snippet']['totalReplyCount'],
                publishedAt = response['items'][i]['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['publishedAt'])

            if 'replies' in response['items'][i]:
                for v in range(len(response['items'][i]['replies']['comments'])):
                    dataReplies = dict(
                            video_id = response['items'][i]['replies']['comments'][v]['snippet']['videoId'],
                            commentId = response['items'][i]['replies']['comments'][v]['id'],
                            username = response['items'][i]['replies']['comments'][v]['snippet']['authorDisplayName'],
                            comment = response['items'][i]['replies']['comments'][v]['snippet']['textDisplay'],
                            like = response['items'][i]['replies']['comments'][v]['snippet']['likeCount'],
                            publishedAt = response['items'][i]['replies']['comments'][v]['snippet']['publishedAt']
                    )
                    all_comments.append(dataReplies)
            all_comments.append(data)

        next_page_token = response.get('nextPageToken')
        more_pages = True
        while more_pages:
            if next_page_token is None:
                more_pages = False
            else:
                
                request = youtube.commentThreads().list(part='snippet, replies', videoId=video_id, maxResults = 100, pageToken = next_page_token)
                response = request.execute()


                for i in range(0, len(response['items'])):
                    data = dict(
                        video_id = response['items'][i]['snippet']['videoId'],
                        commentId = response['items'][i]['snippet']['topLevelComment']['id'],
                        username = response['items'][i]['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['authorDisplayName'],
                        comment = response['items'][i]['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textDisplay'],
                        like = response['items'][i]['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['likeCount'],
                        totalReply = response['items'][i]['snippet']['totalReplyCount'],
                        publishedAt = response['items'][i]['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['publishedAt'])

                    if 'replies' in response['items'][i]:
                        for v in range(len(response['items'][i]['replies']['comments'])):
                            dataReplies = dict(
                                    video_id = response['items'][i]['replies']['comments'][v]['snippet']['videoId'],
                                    commentId = response['items'][i]['replies']['comments'][v]['id'],
                                    username = response['items'][i]['replies']['comments'][v]['snippet']['authorDisplayName'],
                                    comment = response['items'][i]['replies']['comments'][v]['snippet']['textDisplay'],
                                    like = response['items'][i]['replies']['comments'][v]['snippet']['likeCount'],
                                    publishedAt = response['items'][i]['replies']['comments'][v]['snippet']['publishedAt']
                            )
                            all_comments.append(dataReplies)
                    all_comments.append(data)
                next_page_token = response.get('nextPageToken')

        return (all_comments)
```

Help me, this is my first time scraping data

Comment: Your code isn't a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I believe you cannot get all comments due to what I read on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71768274/how-to-extract-all-youtube-comments-using-youtube-api-python/71785217#comment126940415_71785217). Just because a video says it has X amount of comments, that number is more like a estimate - comments might be deleted or marked for approval/spam or any other reason - leaving the video with less comments than the indicator shows.