# Unable to get all comments in a youtube video (Code gets stuck in the last 99%)

Tags: python, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using code that was given in [How to extract all YouTube comments using YouTube API? (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71768274/how-to-extract-all-youtube-comments-using-youtube-api-python). I'm currently facing a problem with it in that it collects comments until it reaches the 99% mark then stops but doesn't crash or give any error outputs. I checked and confirmed that it was not the quota count too.

```
def GetVideoComments(youtube, video_id, datetime_to_check, comments=[], token_list = [], token="") :

    # Stores the total reply count a comment has
    totalReplyCount = 0
    
    # Replies of the comments
    replies = []
    
    try :
        request = youtube.commentThreads().list(part="snippet", 
                                                videoId=video_id, 
                                                maxResults=100,
                                                pageToken=token)
        response = request.execute()
    except HttpError as error :  
        print("Error", error)
        progress_bar.close()
        return comments
    
    progress_bar.update(len(response["items"]))
    
    for item in response["items"] :
        
        comment = item["snippet"]["topLevelComment"]
        timestamp = comment["snippet"]["publishedAt"]
        
        # Skip this comment if it is past the time period we want
        if (timestamp > datetime_to_check) :
            continue
            
        text = comment["snippet"]["textDisplay"]
        comments.append({"timestamp" : timestamp,
                         "comment" : text,
                         "sentiment" : {},
                         "meaningful words" : ""})
        
        # Get the total reply count: 
        totalReplyCount = item["snippet"]["totalReplyCount"]

        # Check if the total reply count is greater than zero, 
        # if so,call GetVideoReplies
        # and extend the "comments" returned list.
        if (totalReplyCount > 0) : 
            comments += GetVideoReplies(comment["id"], datetime_to_check, replies, token_list, None)

        # replies must be cleared as if GetVideoComments is called recursively,
        # replies will still contain its current elements
        replies = []

    if "nextPageToken" in response and response["nextPageToken"] not in token_list : 
        token_list.append(response["nextPageToken"])
        return GetVideoComments(youtube, video_id, datetime_to_check, comments, token_list, response["nextPageToken"])
    else :
        progress_bar.close()
        return comments


def GetVideoReplies(comment_ID, datetime_to_check, replies, token_list, token) : 
    
    try :
        request = youtube.comments().list(part="snippet", 
                                          maxResults=100, 
                                          parentId=comment_ID,
                                          pageToken=token)
        response = request.execute()
    except HttpError as error :  
        print("Error", error)
        progress_bar.close()
        return replies

    progress_bar.update(len(response["items"]))
    
    for item in response["items"] :
        
        # Append the reply's text to replies
        if (item["snippet"]["publishedAt"] > datetime_to_check) :
            continue
        replies.append({"timestamp" : item["snippet"]["publishedAt"],
                         "comment" : item["snippet"]["textDisplay"],
                         "sentiment" : {},
                         "meaningful words" : ""})

    if "nextPageToken" in response and response["nextPageToken"] not in token_list : 
        token_list.append(response["nextPageToken"])
        return GetVideoReplies(comment_ID, datetime_to_check, replies, token_list, response["nextPageToken"])
    else:
        return replies
```

Comment: What does _Code gets stuck in the last 99%_ even mean? You get 99% of the comments and missing 1% or what do you mean? Have you tried to debug it? If not, why not? If yes, what have you found out? Does the code run through completely? Please don't just post code here and expect us to solve your problem without going into more detail.

Comment: What does it output? Add some print statements to help debug.

Comment: You should debug that progress_bar code.